# How long was Han away from "home"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, millennium-falcon

> How long was Han Solo away from the Millennium Falcon? According to Rey, it had changed hands several times from the first thief

This meant that these events either happened all within Rey's lifetime for her to witness (the greater part of thirty years since Endor), or she had at least heard the story from the last guy.

Comment: Unknown from canon as of now.

Comment: The "Incredible Cross-Sections" book just says 'a long time'. No help there.

Comment: We can place a lower bound on it. The hyperdrive has been patched and the ship has changed hands at least three times. That means it's been out of han's possession for at least 3-4 days but probably longer.

Comment: @Richard - Han had enough time buy Eravana, hustle up a scam, get TWO different sets of investors; hire a large crew; and catch the Rathtars. That CLEARLY took far more than your 3-4 days, even for an accomplished con artiste like Han. Take a look at how long the affairs in *Scoundrels* or original *Han Solo Trilogy* lasted

Comment: @dvk - So definitely at least a fortnight?

Comment: @Richard - realistically, based on my deep knowledge of how such things work, at least a month. 2 weeks isn't enough. An average hedge fund doing high-risk investment would take at least a week or 2 for due diligence; and we have 2 here.

Comment: @DVK - True, but Han is a well known smuggler. They've done a lot of their due diligence in advance.

Comment: @DVK Not to mention he got his debtor killed in the process.

Comment: @Richard - Sorry, I beat your lower end estimate by a far larger amount :)

Comment: I removed most of the spoiler protocol because we see Han imply that he has been away from the Falcon for a while in the trailers.  It wasn't a major plot point, nor was it a secret.  The only surprise was when and where it pops up.

Comment: @DVK - Pfft. You cheated and actually looked.

Comment: @Richard - It's not like it's lightsaber practice with the remote. You're allowed to look :)

Comment: @WadCheber I disagree with you, because that's not what I thought of when I saw the trailers. (SPOILERS) I didn't even think of the Millennium Falcon, I thought it was "just a line from the movie". Maybe he came home to Leia of something. Nothing implied he came home from leaving BEFORE the movie. I knew I didn't even think Han's lost his ship up until he made his appearance and used that line. I thought Rey stole the ship and left Han stranded on Jakku.

Comment: @thegreatjedi -  This was already discussed in chat.  The way you wrote the question, it is UNSEARCHABLE.  Please leave it alone.  Titles and questions need to be understandable and searchable.

Comment: See meta:  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/will-we-ever-clean-up-those-ridiculous-spoiler-free-the-force-awakens-question?rq=1

Comment: By "searchable", I mean the question needs to appear in search results if someone searches for the relevant characters, etc.  That wouldn't happen with the question the way you wrote it, because the title is so vague that it is meaningless, and the entire text of the question was hidden.  The version I created is fine - it was discussed and approved in chat, and conforms to the meta consensus on spoilers.

Comment: The new version is okay too.  Thanks for cooperating and you already have my upvote.  :)

Answer (score 4):

At least "years".

From WGA script:

> FINN
>   (climbs down)
>   **Y'ever fly this thing?**
>   INT. MILLENNIUM FALCON - COCKPIT - DAY
>   Rey tosses her staff aside, jumps into the pilot's seat, frantically flips switches. BB-8 rolls in behind her as the ENGINES WHINE to life:
>   REY
>   **No! This ship hasn't been flown in years!**

Comment: @Richard - worth a separate answer. Han - in narrator's words - is more authoritative than Rey's unknown sourcing

Comment: Done, done and done.

Answer (score 1):

With a hat-tip to [DVK's answer from the script](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114379/20774), we know from the film's [Junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization)) that the Falcon has been out of Han's possession for a considerable number of years.

Based on the fact that the narrator notes that the average person would have been expected to have forgotten the (relatively complex) startup sequence for the Falcon, that would seem to imply ten or more years:

> *“Gunner’s position is down below,” she [Rey] called to the young man [Finn]. “You ever fly this thing?” he shouted back. “Nobody’s flown this crate in years."*

and

> *"But Han Solo was far from ready to give up his ghost anytime soon—especially when, after years of searching, he’d finally reunited with the only starship he had ever loved, the Millennium Falcon."*

and

> *"Han left Chewie to bark out directions and hastened into the cockpit, where old habits took over. He sat in his well-worn seat and started flipping switches and turning dials to initiate the launch sequence. Though he hadn’t done it in years, never once did he hesitate; he knew the Falcon’s procedure by heart. Going through it in his head was how Han had coaxed himself to sleep on many a dark night."*